# Get the last record even when the table contains one record

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to get the last record in my table with prepared statement. I have tried both queries below but I am facing problem to get it when the table just contains one record in it.

I am getting result when I execute the query alone but when I execute it in the preparedStatement the `while` loop is not being entered. How can I get the last record even when the table contains one record with prepared statement?

I appreciate any help.

**First query:**

```
select stop_name 
from behaviour 
where mac = ? 
order by behaviour_id desc 
limit 1
```

**Second query:**

```
select stop_name 
from behaviour 
where created_at in (select max(created_at) from behaviour) 
  and mac = ?
```

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS behaviour(
                           behaviour_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                           mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           stop_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           stop_distance INT(11) NOT NULL, 
                           speed INT(11) NOT NULL,
                           created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

**Code**

```
String sql = "select stop_name from behaviour where mac = ? order by behaviour_id desc limit 1";
//String sql = "select stop_name from behaviour where created_at in (select max(created_at) from behaviour) and mac = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedLastStopName = con.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedLastStopName.setString(1, macD);

ResultSet rsLastStopName = preparedLastStopName.executeQuery();

String sto_nam = "";

while (rsLastStopName.next()) {
    sto_nam = rsLastStopName.getString("stop_name");
}
```

Comment: if only one record exists the result should be ''record'' and null or what?

Comment: I am getting result when I execute the query alone but when I execute it in the preparedStatement the while lopp is not being entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select top 1 * from mytable order by insert_date desc

Comment: I am getting this error `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 * from behaviour order by insert_date desc`?

Comment: you using mysql so is little different: select * from mytable order by rowid desc limit 1